# Google Drive used storage is larger online than in my local folder, why?

Tags: google-drive

I have Google Drive application keeping my local Google Drive folder always in sync with the cloud.

I have recently received a warning of "few storage space", where it tells me I have 10GB plus occupied by Google Drive:

[image]

However, my local Google Drive folder has only a bit more than 5GB:

[image]

Is there anything I am missing? How can I find out where this hidden gigabytes are coming from?

Comment: Your Google drive folder does not include email/photos...

Comment: @daBoss yeah, but even considering this, it's 10GB remote vs 5GB local...

Comment: Have you logged into https://drive.google.com and compared the contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One theory is that there is a bunch of stuff in the Trash for Google Drive that was deleted from your local folder, but still counting against your total

[image]

Comment: Seems likely. I opened my Thrash folder, and there are indeed a lot of files and folders. I'm going to delete them permanently and see what happens, thanks so far!

Comment: Click "Trash" icon, then expand the menu "Trash" and select "Empty trash" to empty entire trash. Wait several minutes, refresh Google Drive web site and the total used storage will decrease.

Comment: Also consider the possible revision history for each file.

Answer (score 1):

Drive storage is shared between Google Drive, Gmail, and Google Photos. Are you storing a heap of photos or emails?

Comment: This was voted down, but in my case this was the actual issue. Thanks.